# Is there any way to override "provided" maven scope from command line?

Tags: java, maven

I am quite new to `maven` and inherited an old application which I need to maintain. It has couple of provided libraries (which are provided by the container). I am wondering whether there is any way to generate a war with all the dependencies (including the provided libs) without modifying the **pom.xml**s. (there are quite lot) Is there any way to override the scope for all `libs` from the **command line**?

My challenge is that I am dealing with an enterprise application with quite deep dependency graph and there are lot of provided dependencies all over the places. As a part of my experimentation **I would like to generate a war which is self contained and have all the dependencies. Updating the dozens of poms and changing the scope is not what I am looking for**. Is there any way to do this from the command line?

Comment: It seems likely that you only have to change the one pom that creates the war. In this pom, specify the dependencies that are currently "provided" with the desired scope.

Comment: Actually it helped! Tried it quickly and working fine. I had a wrong perception that I would need to change all of the pom.xml in the whole hierarchy. Thanks for the hint, will try to google and understand how the magic happened. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to change the one pom that creates the war. In this pom, specify the dependencies that are currently "provided" with the desired scope.

Maven computes the transitive dependencies for the war project based on the modules that it depends on and is bringing in those particular dependencies with a provided scope. You can think of this as defining the default configuration for those dependencies. You can override the default (inherited) scope by explicitly specifying the dependency in your war module with the desired scope.

In my opinion, the non-war modules probably should not be setting the scope to provided and instead should leave this decision to the module that will actually create the runnable artifact (e.g., your war module). For example, if you were to make a fat jar to execute the code as a standalone app (vs. a war in a container that provides those dependencies), you probably would want to include them in the jar.